# using libevent to read a continuous http stream and sending data at random times

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, libevent, http-streaming

Firstly I think I need to say that I'm still learning C++ so apologies if this is blindingly obvious/simple.

I'm trying to use the libevent library (by trying I've looked through code in the sample folder and tested some) in my C++ program to consume an http stream. I'm wondering if anyone can provide me with an example of how I'd go about connecting to a URL e.g. live.domain.com, sending the appropriate headers, read the data returned and send data back over the same connection...
I'm not sure libevent does any blocking connections but just to be explicit, I'm after non-blocking samples.

**Why am I trying to do this?**

I'm using an API which requires you to open a connection and it keeps it alive unless there's an error. It'll periodically send status texts to the connected client until it receives a string with an ID over the same connection. At which point it starts sending data back about the ID given... I'm not entirely sure sending data back over the same connection after the initial request is strictly compliant but that's what the server expects so it'll work...if I knew how

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "send data back over the same connection". Do you mean sending a second HTTP request over the same connection, or does this change to some weird non-HTTP protocol midstream?

Comment: It expects a json string to be sent back midstream to subscribe to messages for an ID. You can send multiple IDs as separate strings and at any time while the connection is open. Basically only the initial request is expected to follow HTTP (in the sense that you send headers and new line delimiter to mark the end of the request) any subsequent messages are pretty much the same as if you had a raw socket opened between to programs and sending arbitrary strings between them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck. Given that this isn't really HTTP, I don't think you're going to be happy using a HTTP library - even if you get it to work today after a lot of frustration, it could easily be broken tomorrow. This is too rare to be a supported feature.

But...it sounds like it's also simple enough that you could just open a raw TCP connection with libevent, manually send something that looks kind of like an HTTP request, and handle it with raw sockets from there. You don't want the extra stuff a HTTP library gets you anyway (additional transfer/content encodings, proxy support, SSL, compatibility with other protocol versions, ...)

As far as examples go, look at the [libevent book](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html#_launching_connections_by_hostname). In particular, the a "Trivial HTTP v0 client" that seems very close to what you want. Good luck!

Comment: yeah I left libevent alone in the end. I need proxy support though so I'm looking into zeromq, much much better documented. I've already got it doing what I want

Comment: Huh. Well, I'm glad you got it working. I'm very surprised to hear that a proxy server put up with that.